# Getting encoded characters as a response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

URL: http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf

I want to request the above URL and get the PDF file as a response, when I do it in postman or insomnia, I could see the output as a PDF. However, when I tried with code, I am getting garbage values in the front end

```
var axios = require("axios").default;
var options = {method: 'GET', url: 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf'};

axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
  res.send(response.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

The output which I am getting

```
%PDF-1.3 %���� 1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Outlines 2 0 R /Pages 3 0 R >> endobj 2 0 obj << /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >> endobj 3 0 obj << /Type /Pages /Count 2 /Kids [ 4 0 R 6 0 R ] >> endobj 4 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 3 0 R /Resources << /Font << /F1 9 0 R >> /ProcSet 8 0 R >> /MediaBox [0 0 612.0000 792.0000] /Contents 5 0 R >> endobj 5 0 obj << /Length 1074 >> stream 2 J BT 0 0 0 rg /F1 0027 Tf 57.3750 722.2800 Td ( A Simple PDF File ) Tj ET BT /F1 0010 Tf 69.2500 688.6080 Td ( This is a small demonstration .pdf file - ) Tj ET BT /F1 0010 Tf 69.2500 664.7040 Td ( just for use in the Virtual Mechanics tutorials. More text. And more ) Tj ET BT /F1 0010 Tf 69.2500 652.7520 Td ( text. And more text. And more text. And more text. ) Tj ET BT /F1 0010 Tf 69.2....
```

Expected output

[image]

Comment: Please remove the regex tag, this has nothing to do with regex

Comment: @PeterThoeny Sorry sir, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Hi @uingtea, res.send() will sends the HTTP response to the front-end

Answer (score 3):

If you set the [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header to application/pdf, the file will display properly.

```
const axios = require("axios").default;
const options =  { 
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://meltwaternews.com/ext/mediac/311919964.pdf',
    responseType: "arraybuffer"
};

axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
    res.header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    res.send(response.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

I've updated the answer to ensure we get the responseType of 'arraybuffer', see axios docs at https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config

Comment: Hi @Terry, thanks for looking into this, actually it works for few PDF files. however, It will only show the blank slide for the other few links like below
https://meltwaternews.com/ext/mediac/311919964.pdf

Comment: Hi @RAJENDRAH, I've updated my answer to ensure we get a binary response. This should now work.

Comment: Hi @Terry, thank you so much brother, you really saved my life, may God bless you.

Comment: Great, glad to be of help!  Have a great day! 